# Ubuntu 18.04 internet speed meter or monitor

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, download-speed

I tried searching everywhere, but I wasn't able to find a taskbar Internet speed monitor or meter for Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a way to get one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following GNOME extensions...

The place to search is [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

I found these...

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1461/internet-speed-meter/

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1085/simple-net-speed/

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/

Comment: Thank you i will try and will let you know if it works after some time.